# Default iPhone screenshot programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I tried two different ways to create a screenshot, but unfortunately they don't work as I need, I have an RMMapView that is blank on the screenshot. When I create snapshot manually on my device it works perfectly, and the map view is on the screen. So I would like to achieve the same result programmatically. Is it possible somehow as I tried? Or what is the right way to do that? (To reproduce that type of screenshot)

```
- (UIImage *) takeScreenshot {

    //1. version
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;


    //2. version
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

    CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];

    UIImage *image=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;

}
```

Comment: when do you call takeScreenshot?

Comment: @MustafaIbrahim after button tap.

Comment: Does the map is on screen when you tab the button?

Comment: @MustafaIbrahim of course.

Answer (score 0):

Actually You can use a method called takeSnapshot in a RMMapView.

```
UIImage *image = self.mapView.takeSnapshot
```

[Update]
Can you try this method instead

```
CGSize size = self.view.bounds.size;
CGRect cropRect = self.mapView.bounds

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * mapImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(mapImage.CGImage, cropRect);
UIImage * cropImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(cropImage, nil, nil, nil);

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Good luck

Comment: I know this solution, it returns a different image then the current view and has bad quality. This is the reason I want to reproduce the "manual" screenshot.

Comment: You are right. there is an open issue with the same reason on RMMapView  Github repo https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/issues/589

Comment: Thanks, I already checked this. Unfortunately I don't have time, therefore the fastest way would be the screenshot.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still the same as my attempts.